# mysql_num_rows doesn't return anything when no rows are found

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my head around this issue.

```
  $can = $r6['candidate_id'] ; 
  $checkquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidate 
  WHERE candidate_id ='$can' and type='facrep'") or die(mysql_error());  
  if (mysql_num_rows($checkquery) > 0) {
     echo ">0" ; 
  }else {
     echo "0" ; 
  }
```

If there is a record in the database, it succesfully returns `>0` but if there are no records, it doesn't return anything, not even `0`. Consequently, the `else` statement never works.

Ideas?

Comment: Make sure you sanitize  `$can = $r6['candidate_id'] ; ` if you're going to use mysql functions.

Comment: Unless there is something your not showing us.. That code will work. You must be returning rows.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: First you have to check return values of mysql_num_rows(). It returns "FALSE" on failure Go through this -  http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_num_rows returns bool false on no rows found.So you to re-write the code as

```
  $can = $r6['candidate_id'] ; 
  $checkquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidate 
  WHERE candidate_id ='$can' and type='facrep'") or die(mysql_error());  
  if (mysql_num_rows($checkquery)) {
     echo ">0" ; 
  }else {
     echo "0" ; 
 }
```

this would help you out hopefully!

Comment: [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) certainly does NOT return `false` when no rows are found. It returns `false` in case of error.